# find a way to make a command not possible to execute

Tags: linux, shell, command

I have a user in linux

and i have a problem, because the user in linux is accessed by many users and in some times somebody for error write crontab -r and delete all crontabs.

Is there a way to lock the command: "crontab -r"? (i am not the user root, only have this permisions in this user)

But i need that all the persons in the user can create crontab ("crontab -e") or list the crontab ("crontab -l")

I have a red hat server.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can change the permissions on that program to only allow certain users to execute it.  Something like "sudo chmod crontab [permissions]"

Comment: Does this help:- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90998/block-particular-command-in-linux-for-specific-user

Comment: Once you've got that figured out, perhaps you ought to consider not using shared accounts...

Comment: When your current mess requires constant firefighting, there's no time to discover things like deployment process and version control. Let's hope they find better jobs where they can learn.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to prevent is carelessness, a simple wrapper in `/usr/local/bin/crontab` is all it takes.

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
 -r) echo "$0 -r disabled; aborting" >&2
     exit 1;;
esac
exec /usr/bin/crontab "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make crontab into a shell script that would catch this and throw an error. How you would tell when the operation is proper or not, though, is up to you. Since many different people log in with the same username, there's no intrinsic way to tell when it's proper to do something and when it's not.